# steam install missing files

Tags: steam

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on an Orange PI 5 Plus SBC.  I've tried multiple ways (command line and web install) to install Steam in my Ubuntu instance.  Each time I receive the same error about missing files when I run the program:

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages:
libc6:arm64 libc6:i386 libegl1:arm64 libgbm1:arm64 libgl1-mesa-dri:arm64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1:arm64 libgl1:i386 steam-libs-amd64:amd64 steam-libs-i386:i386

Press return to proceed with the installation: 
.................................................................................................E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libc6:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libdb1-compat libnss-nis libnss-nisplus libcrypt1

Package libgl1:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libgl1-amber-dri

E: Package 'libc6:i386' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libgl1-mesa-dri:i386' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libgl1:i386' has no installation candidate
```

I've tried installing the replacement packages with no resolution.  I've searched the forums here and see this is a common issue but none of the suggested fixes has resolved the issue.   Please help if you have any ideas about resolving this.   Thanks for reading.

Comment: Isn't Steam only available for i386 architecture? What made you think it was available in the first place?

Comment: @mikewhatever the common "but it's listed in the repos" for the metapackage problem applies for Steam.  See my answer.

Comment: Steam will not run on a pi.

Answer (score 3):

**Steam does not support any non-x86 boards or system architectures.**  That is why you can't install it.

Steam does not support ARM processors or architectures.  It is only usable on x86-based systems (so amd64 and i386 architectures using Linux nomenclature for architectures).

You will **not** be able to run Steam on the Orange Pi boards.  Or any ARM-based boards.  It is simply not supported, so you cannot get Steam to work on your system.